# How to save shortest path attributes to a new layer with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, dijkstra

I'm using QGIS 2.14.22 Essen. I'm using network analysis `dijkstra()` to find the shortest path from p1 to p2 on a power grid network. But what i get from it is the shortest path without any attributes and fields.

I have found a way to save the shortest path attributes and fields to a new layer, but it requires to apply a buffer over the "empty" shortest path and then use `qgis:selectbylocation` to select only the power grid features that are **inside** the buffer. Is  it possible to do the same only using `dijkstra()`??

Here is the code, it may help someone else:

```
##-- coding: utf-8  --##

import processing
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.networkanalysis import *

########--- Finding Shortest Path from p1 to p2 ----#########

# Load the power grid network
layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\...\power_grid.shp",
"power_grid", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer]) 
layer = processing.getObject('power_grid')

(x1,y1)=(357719.47,6307582.61)  #p1
(x2,y2)=(357801.11,6307695.86)  #p2

director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector(layer,-1,'','','',3)
director.addProperter(QgsDistanceArcProperter())
builder = QgsGraphBuilder(layer.crs())
from_point = QgsPoint(x1,y1)
to_point = QgsPoint(x2,y2)
tied_points =director.makeGraph(builder,[from_point,to_point])
graph = builder.graph()
# compute the route from p1 to p2
from_id = graph.findVertex(tied_points[0])
to_id = graph.findVertex(tied_points[1])
(tree,cost) = QgsGraphAnalyzer.dijkstra(graph,from_id,0)
route_points = []
curPos = to_id
while (curPos != from_id):
    in_vertex = graph.arc(tree[curPos]).inVertex()
    route_points.append(graph.vertex(in_vertex).point())
    curPos = graph.arc(tree[curPos]).outVertex()
route_points.append(from_point)

result = 'C:\...\p1_to_p2.shp'
writer = VectorWriter(result,None,[],2,layer.crs())
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(route_points))
writer.addFeature(fet)
del writer
#processing.load(result)

###- Creating a buffer over the "empty" shortest path found above -###

#lyr is the shortest path generate above, without attributes
lyr = QgsVectorLayer("C:\...\p1_to_p2.shp",
"shortestpathEmpty", "ogr")

# Next, visualize the shortest path on the map:
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([lyr])    

# Access the layer's features:
fts = lyr.getFeatures()

# Creating a buffer layer in memory
buffLyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:29189', 'Buffer' ,"memory") 
index=QgsSpatialIndex()

#Creating the buffer over the empty shortest path
#It's not necesary a for to do it, but it works
for f in fts:
    buff = f.geometry().buffer(1,2) 
    pr = buffLyr.dataProvider()
    b = QgsFeature()
    b.setGeometry(buff)
    pr.addFeatures([b])

# Update the buffer layer's extents:
buffLyr.updateExtents()
# Set the buffer layer's transparency to 80
buffLyr.setLayerTransparency(80)  
# Add the buffer layer to the map:
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([buffLyr])

#####--- Saving the shortest path with attributes to a new layer ---#####

#Selecting the features from power_grid that are 'within' the buffer with 
#the empty shortest path shape
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation",layer,buffLyr,[u'within'],0)

power_grid= qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
# Saving the shortest path with attributes 
result='C:\...\p1_to_p2withattr.shp'
# Using geoprocessing alg "Save selected features"
processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', layer, result)
#Add saved path with attributes to map
processing.load(result)
iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

[image]

[image: Power grid network]

Applying a buffer and using `qgis:selectbylocation`, this is the result:
[image]
[image]

Finally, I'm able to get the shortest path attributes in a new layer:
[image]